# Xamarin forms MatserdetailPage won't show the hamburger icon

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a `MasterDetailPage` where the `MasterPage` opens when I swipe to the right but the hamburger menu icon won't show up.
I'm testing on Android and if you need more information please ask :)

```xml
<MasterDetailPage
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:dpsApp"
    x:Class="dpsApp.MainPage"
    xmlns:flex="clr-namespace:Flex.Controls;assembly=Flex"
    MasterBehavior="Default">
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Title="Master">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End">
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>

<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <ContentPage Title="Detail" BackgroundColor="#e7e7e7">
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout x:Name="NoInternetStack"  IsVisible="False" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">

            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

Comment: I added an answer with my xaml code

Comment: Okay sorry I hope it's correct now

Comment: Pretty good. Thank you =)

Answer (score 0):

Your master page misses a value for the Icon property.

Normally your XAML should look like something like this:

```xml
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Title="Master" Icon="hamburger.png">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End">
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

Comment: I had it like that but it doesn't work. I know my MasterPage worked once without using an image but I realized today that this isn't the case anymore :)

Comment: Yeah the image itself is also required as image resource in each target project too of course...

Comment: I know but it doesn't work. But one week earlier I had it without setting an icon and it worked .

Comment: Weird... now the docs are clear on this though, icon is what draws it on screen: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page

Comment: Hmm the hamburger had even animations I thought Xamarin would do this on his own. I'm new in Xamarin so there are alot of things I don't understand :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page)

For the menu icon to appear you need to set it, set the Icon property on your `MasterPage` like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MasterDetailPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MasterDetailForms" 
    x:Class="MasterDetailForms.MainPage"
    MasterBehavior="Default"
    Title="MasterDetails">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <ContentPage Title="Master" 
            Icon="hamburger.png">
            <ContentPage.Content>
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start">
                    <Label Text="option 1"/>
                    <Label Text="option 2"/>
                    <Label Text="option 3"/>
                    <Label Text="option 4"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentPage.Content>
        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>

    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <ContentPage Title="Detail" BackgroundColor="#e7e7e7">
            <StackLayout>
                <StackLayout x:Name="NoInternetStack"  IsVisible="False" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Content"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Also on Android, the Icon won't appear on tablets with `MasterBehaviour` set to `Default`. If you want the icon to show I would set it to `Popover` in that scenario.

Comment: I had it like that but it doesn't work. I know my MasterPage worked once without using an image but I realized today that this isn't the case anymore :)